# jsTree - return node value

Tags: jquery, jstree

I have the following code:

```
for (i = 0, j = data.selected.length; i < j; i++) {
       r.push(data.instance.get_node(data.selected[i]).text.trim());
}
 alert('Selected: ' + r.join(', '));
```

This correctly brings back the text of the node but I'd like to also bring back the Node value as well - I have tried various forms of:

```
r.push(data.instance.get_node(data.selected[i]).id());
r.push(data.instance.get_node(data.selected[i]).val());
```

But no joy - any suggestions welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$.jstree.reference(data.reference).get_node(data.reference)
```

It will return you the jsTree node.